# Css footer's behavior on window resizing

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I made a sticky footer using few tricks I learned [here](http://mystrd.at/modern-clean-css-sticky-footer/), but I want to limit the minimum window resizing to **700 pixels**.

When I resize the window, when the window reaches less then  700 pixels there's a white space left beside the footer, in other words it doesn't fit the whole screen.

I'm not sure what's wrong here..here is my  jsBin example:

```
`https://output.jsbin.com/gawidovijo`
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: on `body`, add `position: relative;` and change `margin: 0 0 100px;` to `padding: 0 0 100px;`

Comment: @MichaelCoker intresting! can you add a little explaination why your suggestion works? how is it different from my?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On `body`, add `position: relative;` and change `margin: 0 0 100px;` to `padding: 0 0 100px;`

Your footer is absolutely positioned, and it needs a relative parent to be positioned in relation to. Without it, it will position itself relative to the `html` element, which is only as wide as the viewport. Any time you absolutely position an element, be sure to relatively position the parent that you want the absolutely positioned element to be positioned within. Since you're defining the `max-width` of your page on `body`, it makes sense to position the footer relative to `body`.

And with that change, your footer will now be positioned in relation to `body`, and that means the bottom margin on `body` will appear below the footer, so to get the footer to display in that `100px` space, you need to change that space from a `margin` to a `padding` so that the footer will position itself there.

Answer (score 0):

Slashy,

I don't see the white space you referenced.  I reviewed in FF, Chrome and IE11 on Windows 7.  Perhaps you simply need to clear your browser cache?

A few other items to be aware of:

- position: absolute; is in relationship to the parent container.  You
  might want to use position: fixed; which uses the browser window as
  the parent.
- You will probably also want to use padding-bottom on the
  body rather than margin-bottom.
- One last thing you might want to include is box-sizing: border-box;  By default box-sizing is set to
  content-box.  If you set the width to 100% and then add padding, it
  will be wider than 100% with content-box.

When absolutely positioning elements, you need to define the parent's position if you want to use the parent's position in relationship to the absolutely positioned child.  Here is an example where I want a div at the top right of my content.  Here is the HTML starting in the body:

```
<body>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">This element is in the top right</div>
    <p>Here is the parent content</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.parent{
  position: relative;
}
.child{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

If I didn't define position: relative; in .parent, then .child would be positioned based on body.

Absolutely positioning things can be a little tricky at first.  I hope this helps you.

Comment: Looks like Michael beat me to the answer.  the only new info my post provides is position: fixed; and box-sizing: border-box;  Good luck!